# How to avoid "package cycle"

Tags: go, package, go-gin

I am writing a REST API using Gin.

The package "controller" implements the controllers (also called "handler").

The package "main" implements the application entry point. This entry point defines routes, and associated routes to controllers.

Thus, the package "main" uses the package "controller".

I'd like to write unit tests for the controllers. And I'd like to write them within the package "controller".

However, in order to test the controller, I need to set up the routes to the controllers. And, of course, **I don't want duplicated code** : I don't want to set up the routes within the package "main" (for the application) **and** within the package "controller" (for the unit tests).

Thus, I've written the file "route.go" that implements set up of routes.

The problem : the package "main" uses the package "controller"... and the package "controller" uses the package "main".

[image: package cycle]

I don't see how to solve this problem.

Of course, I can write unit tests within the package "main". I've done it and this solution is *technically* OK. But, it is not *good*. Testing the controllers should be done within the package "controller".

I can set the routes within the package "controller". But this solution implies that I put **all** the controllers within the same sub-package (let's say "controller"). But I'd prefer to organize controllers regarding the resources they manage (controllers that manage users within the package "controller.user", controllers that manage profiles within the package "controller.profiles"...):

```
├───bootstrap
└───controller
    ├───profile
    └───user
```

I can set the routes to user controllers within the package "controller.user", the routes to profile controllers within the package "controller.profile"... that would work. But is there a way to set all routes within the same GO source file ?

Any idea ?

## Update 1

Response to the question (@Adrian):

> Why would you need to configure all the routes in order to test any one handler?

Because the routes define the parameters to retrieve from the URI:

```golang
router := gin.Default()
router.DELETE("/user/:id", action.Delete)
```

```golang
type RequestDelete struct {
    Id uint64 `uri:"id"`
}
...
// c *gin.Context
// s *RequestDelete
if err := c.ShouldBindUri(s); nil != err { ... }
```

You need to declare "id" in the route "`/user/:id`" (unless you can do otherwise).

## Update 2

The real problem here is not related to Golang.

In order to bind a URI parameter to a variable (a structure field), you first need to "declare" it. It seems logical, doesn't it ? And because URIs are, obviously, deeply coupled to routes (*inseparable, in fact*), you must define routes **before** you can bind a URI parameter to a variable. See the "update 1".

Therefore, what happens if you try to declare routes in one package and bind URI parameters in another package ?

Please keep in mind that URI parameters binding is done within (request) handlers.Thus, the question above becomes :

> what happens if you try to declare routes in one package (*it can be "main", or any other package*) and bind URI parameters in another package (*the package that implements the request handlers*) ?

Response :

1. the package that declares the routes will import the package that implements the (request) handlers. Because, declaring a route amounts to associate a (request) handler to a URI.
2. in the test file that implements tests for a (given) handler, you import the package that declares the routes *to this (given) handler* (assuming these are distinct packages, of course).

**Therefore, you necessarily end up with a cycle, unless you declare the route associated with a handler within the same package that implements the handler.**

Comment: You're referring to the routes and controllers as if they're different things, but it's unclear what they are. Usually routes are handled by handlers, and those can be united tested independently. Why would you need to configure all the routes in order to test any one handler?

Comment: Denis, the first thing you should realize is that you can't import package `main`, so even if there was no import cycle in your code you'd not be able to import `main`. If you put the route setup in a package separate from main (and have main import it instead) then you could reuse it within the controller's tests if you use the `..._test` package name in the `..._test.go` files (this creates a separate package for testing even though the files are located in the same directory).

Comment: @Adrian Because you need to declare the URI parameters (see Update 1).

Comment: @mkopriva I've thought of this solution. But, unless I've made a mistake, it does not solve the issue. The compiler still complains about a cycle : "`import cycle not allowed in test`". I'll write a very simple example.

Comment: @DenisBeurive You must have made a mistake then, it works without error the way I've described it.

Comment: @mkopriva I've tested in a very simple project. It works. However, within my big preject, there is still a cycle. I'll look more in details.

Comment: I see the problem. The basic problem is that there is a strong coupling between the routes and the handlers (since I must declare the URI parameters prior to their extraction) - see "Update 1". Thus : (1) I import the "handler" package from my "bootstrap" package (that sets the routes) (2) I import the "boorstrap" package from my "handler" package (because I need to set the routes before I can test). There must be a way to test handlers that require URI parameters without setting the routes first. I'll look at the Gin framework.

Comment: No matter how I set the URI parameters : through the routes or otherwise... I don't want to perform the set more than once! Thus the real problem here is the strong coupling between handler and URI parameters declaration.

Comment: @mkopriva see "Update 2".

Comment: I still don't get why you can't use a separate test package, whether in the same dir or outside. __Whenever__ you have an import cycle (e.g., package `A` depends on package `B`, but `B` also depends on `A`), you have basically two options: #1 put everything into one package (`A` or `B`, doesn't matter); #2 create a third package `C` and have `A` and `B` depend on `C`.

Comment: Declaring all the routes to test a handler still seems unnecessary. You can create a test context and fill in any params you need for your test. For example: https://blog.canopas.com/golang-unit-tests-with-test-gin-context-80e1ac04adcd#1b6e

Comment: @Adrian Yes, of course. We don't need to declare all routes in order to test one handler. We just need to declare the route to this handler. Note that this is true only if the handler retrieves URI parameters. Otherwise, there is no coupling at all between routes (URI) and handlers.

Comment: @mkopriva Good point. This second approach might be cleaner.

Comment: @DenisBeurive you don't even need to do that. See the link in my comment. You don't need routing to test a handler.